# Calculate SVG viewBox to show full image?

Tags: svg

I have a large SVG image (.svg file on my disk, not an element in a webpage) which has the viewBox parameter on the SVG element set to crop the image. Rather than cropping, I want to show the entire SVG image. How can I figure out what values I need to put in for height and width in order to show the full image without cropping or extra whitespace?

Comment: It would be the union of the bounding boxes of all the elements in the image.

Comment: Any easy approach would be to open it in a vector illustration program, change the artboard/bounding box, and then re-save it.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Sure, that makes sense. If you could put together instructions for how to find that union, I think it would make an excellent answer!